# SQL Computed Column , Coallesce , Two DateTime Fields , Index

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have in my database following two Columns :

**Delivery_Date** (DateTime)
**Delivery_Override** (DateTime)

*( I must preserve the Original Delivery Date for other things I do )*

I created following Computed Column

**Delivery_Packdate** 
*formula* : `(coalesce(nullif([Delivery_Override],''),[Delivery_Date]))`

and now I can do a select like this :

```
select * from Deliveries where Delivery_PackDate = '2019-09-24'
```

and this automatically selects the Overriden Date if filled or else the original date.

the Problem is I would like to index this , but SQL will not allow this because it is non-deterministic .

I suppose I am doing something wrong here , how can I solve this correctly ? Any tips?

Thank you.

Comment: Your _table_ has those _columns_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are converting to a string.  The following works fine:

```
create table t (
    Delivery_Override datetime,
    Delivery_Date datetime
);

alter table t add dt as (coalesce(Delivery_Override, Delivery_Date)) persisted;

create index idx_t_dt on t(dt);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5051736d72249181fce93cf7e69a4401) is a db<>fiddle.

There is no such thing as a date/time with the value `''`.